# type object 'ContentType' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am using djangae with some third party applications like all-auth, django-invitations and django rest framework. When I hit python manage.py migrate I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: type object 'ContentType' has no attribute 'objects'
```

The full trace is following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 26, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib/djangae/core/management/__init__.py", line 43, in execute_from_command_line
return _execute_from_command_line(djangae_namespace.sandbox, argv, parser=djangae_parser, **overrides)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib/djangae/core/management/__init__.py", line 68, in _execute_from_command_line
return django_management.execute_from_command_line(argv)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 227, in handle
self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/core/management/sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal
**kwargs
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
File "/home/salman/Workspace/chaipani/lib-vendor/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 63, in create_permissions
ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
AttributeError: type object 'ContentType' has no attribute 'objects'
```

My installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'djangae',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'djangae.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djangae.contrib.security',
'django.contrib.sites',

'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
'invitations',

]
```

Any help anyone?

Comment: If those typos 'djangae', 'djangae.contrib.contenttypes' and 'djangae.contrib.security' are also in your code, then that might be the problem.

Comment: These are not typos, I am actually running djangae, and for running it we need djangae apps in installed apps.

Comment: Just so you know, [Django is supported on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) without having to use this middleware.